# List item URL target open in a new tab

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

Have one HTML and two PDF documents kept on the DB server for the APEX schema. These are accessed by clicking on a List item. Currently these work... however the documents open in the same tab. Want them to open in a new tab.

The URL target for the HTML document is...

> **&GBL_SERVER.&GBL_IMAGEPATH.mcs_faq.htm**

URL targets for the PDF documents are...

> **&GBL_SERVER.&GBL_IMAGEPATH.PermitFees.pdf**
>
> **&GBL_SERVER.&GBL_IMAGEPATH.Map14ft6in.pdf**

All the URL targets use two different shared component Application Items, which are set with an Application Process - creating global items used in the URL link. These change dynamically depending if you are the development, test, or production server.

Have tried changing the URL target by adding JavaScript...

> javascript:window.open("&GBL_SERVER.&GBL_IMAGEPATH.mcs_faq.htm.","_blank")

Have also tried going to the "User Defined Attributes" and adding... **target="_blank"**

Nothing I have done appears to be working. Perhaps the JavaScript syntax is not quite correct? Are there any suggestions what else should be looked at please? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My URL comes from a database field. Idefined the data as

**[http://xxx.zzzzz.com/sss/"](http://xxx.zzzzz.com/sss/%22) target="_blank**